# nested form in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am working with nested angular form. I am using from arrays. But in this from using two dynamic component which add when we click multiple times. But the problem is when we add the first item the second one are automatically get added in form.i am using two component **titleXIX** and **ItemCCp** which are completely different but shares the common array.when we addNewCCpForm the titleXIX form also get added. how to solve the issue

```
getFormBuilder() {
    this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
      orderType: 1,
      entity: 3,
      refusalReason: '',
      coordinator: this.fb.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      patient: this.fb.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      hsp: this.fb.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      vendor: this.fb.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required]
      }),
      vendorContact: this.fb.group({
        // TODO : right now hardcoded as order creation failing if vendor-contact empty.
        id: '4'
      }),
      providerGroup: this.fb.group({
        id:11
      }),
      shippingAddress: this.fb.group({
        city: '',
        line1: '',
        line2: '',
        state: '',
        zip: ''
      }),
      customDetails: this.fb.group({
        ccpForm: true,
        titleXIXForm: false,
        extraInformation: '',
        ccpIcd9: ['', Validators.required],
        estimatedDeliveryDate: '',
        ccpDateOfServiceFrom: ['', Validators.required],
        ccpDateOfServiceTo: ['', Validators.required],
        ccpDiagAndMedNecessityOfServices: '',
        lines: this.fb.array([
          this.CPPItem()
        ]),
        initial: this.fb.group({
          from: '',
          to: '',
          checked: false
        }),
        recertification: this.fb.group({
          from: '',
          to: '',
          checked: false
        }),
        revision: this.fb.group({
          from: '',
          to: '',
          checked: false
        }),
        ccpJustification: '',
        ccpRevision: '',
        durationNeed: '',
        durationSupply: '',
        lastSeenPhysician:['',Validators.required]
      }),
    });
  }

  addNewCCPItem() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['customDetails'].get('lines');
    control.push(this.CPPItem());
  }

  removeCCPItem(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['customDetails'].get('lines');
    control.removeAt(i);
  }

  addItemXIX() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['customDetails'].get('lines');
    control.push(this.CPPItem());
  }

  removeItemXIX(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['customDetails'].get('lines');
    control.removeAt(i);
  }

  CPPItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      additionalDocuments:this.fb.array([]),
      hcpcs:'',
      quantityFrequence:'',
      beyondQtyLimit: true,
      customItem : false,
      icd9:['',Validators.required],
      justification:'',
      price:'',
      priorAuthRequired: false,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please, explain your question. I can't understand what you want.

Comment: addNewCCPItem() and addItemXIX() are two functions. In my HTML I write the code for multiple entries. when we click the button an event occurs. which when triggers the multiple entries. from here it works well.But at the time of the first trigger as both the triggers are called means addNewCCPItem() and addItemXIX(). as I show the code both the entries are used the same form array. when we add controls for one group the controls for second are automatically get added..that's the problem

Comment: Hi, we (at work) have been working on that topic and I gave a proper answer you may want to check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457210/2398593 :)